# Split table inheritance in Entity Framework using fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have 2 sql tables as follows:

Message
.MessageID
.MessageType
.Recipient
.Source
.ProcessedOn
.Result
.SMS_Text
.Email_Subject
.Email_Body

EmailAttachment
.EmailAttachmentID
.MessageID
.Filename


I wish to split the messages table (using EF fluent api mapping) to two seperate classes (EmailMessage and SMSMessage) that both inherit from a base class Message.  The MessageType value would define which class to use.  The classes would look as follows:

Message (interface in principle, not to be instantiated)
.MessageID
.Recipient
.Source
.ProcessedOn
.Result

EmailMessage
.Subject
.Body
.Attachments

EmailAttachment
.EmailAttachmentID
.EmailMessage
.Filename

SMSMessage
.SMSText

Any ideas on how to achieve this using EF fluent api mapping?

Comment: I've got same problem in EF6. Have you found any solution ?